# React native: No active iOS device found

Tags: ios, react-native

Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500)

React Native 0.61.5

[image: React native: No active iOS device found]

After launching iOS app running `npm run start` and `npm run start:ios` from the terminal. The app builds successfully and launches on the iOS simulator (iPhone 11 - 13.2.2) but an error appears underneath with 'No active iOS device found'.

Why is this error showing even though the app launches and runs?

Comment: Because it by default run on device. So if there is no device connected then it will simply display this error and run on simulator. This is not effect anything else.

Comment: Oh yes, it's set to default because I never specified --simulator="iPhone X"? Or it's just telling me I never connected my device?